# Installing ESXi on Dell Inspiron 7720

Tags: esxi

I'm trying to install ESXi on an old Dell Inspiron 7720 laptop that I have laying around, but it won't detect my NIC.

According to `lspci -nn` it's a `Realtek RTL8101/2/6E [10ec:8136] NIC`.

I tried running an ESXi Customizer script to include a r8101 package driver in my installation ISO, but it still refuses to detect the NIC.

Am I wrong to conclude it's not a r8101 NIC? What else can I try to get this to work?

Comment: Laptops aren't exactly the best for ESXi; while you *can* do this, I don't think it'll work properly with the NIC.  For my ESXi builds I always try and use systems that have Intel NICs, they work the best.

Comment: @ThomasWard Honestly, it's just an hobby project and I had this hardware laying around (no screen is attached to it anymore). I just want to use it to play around with setting up vlan's and such without the overhead of a host-OS (ie: Vmware workstation on a Windows 10 installation)

Comment: Have you contacted VMWare support about the network device not being detected?

Comment: @Ramhound last time I did that they told me to refer to their "Supported Devices" and "Supported Hardware" lists and didn't give me any help.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not a commercially licensed version of ESXi, so don't expect any help from them :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some lookup on the `lspci` codes [that specific device identifier identifier shows three separate potential series of cards that match that ID](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10ec/8136) - RTL8101, RTL8102, and RTL8106E.

It looks to me like it could be any one of those cards, and I can't be absolutely certain which driver you need - it may use the 8101-series of driver, but it might not.

So to answer your original question, "Am I wrong to conclude it's not a r8101 NIC?", you are not wrong to conclude this - it could be one of three RTL810X series cards (where X is a number).

---

In my experience trying to set up ESXi servers, however, I've only ever had luck with Broadcom and Intel NICs, either as on board (say, the Broadcom built-in in my workstation-turned-hypervisor HP Z400) or PCI/PCIe expansion (say, a 4-port gigabit Intel NIC expansion card from Dell or HP servers added in) NIC cards.  (Either Broadcom or Intel, regardless of on-board or expansion, have given me luck, while Realtek has never worked for me)

It also looks to me like [there are other headaches with Realtek adapters as well](https://serverfault.com/questions/678195/drivers-of-rtl8111-8168-pci-express-gigabit-ethernet-controller-for-esxi-6-0/678196) in ESXi, though not necessarily that series card you have.

Comment: hmm okay, then either way I'm probably not gonna get any further by attempting to install ESXi on this machine since there are no other driver packages available for other RTL810X cards - Thanks for the information though

Comment: ESXi is notoriously limited in the amount of network adapters it supports.

Comment: I ended up using Proxmox instead, it's a bit harder to configure, but seems capable of the same features